# Reading first n lines of a CSV into a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a CSV file I'd like to read into a dictionary for subsequent insertion into a MongoDB collection entitled projects.

I accomplished this with the following:

```
with open('opendata_projects.csv') as f:
    records = csv.DictReader(f)
    projects.insert(records)
```

However, I found my poor sandbox account couldn't hold all the data. In turn, I'd like to read in the first *n* lines so I can play around with the data and get used to working with MongoDB.

First I checked the docs for the `csv.DictReader` function:

> class csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)

But the function doesn't seem to allow for entering in the number of rows I'd like as a parameter.

So I attempted to do so by writing the following code:

```
with open('opendata_projects.csv') as f:
    records = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in records:
        if i <= 100:
            projects.insert(i)
```

Which was followed by the error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() <= int()
```

This prompted me to look into dictionaries further, and I found they are unordered. Nevertheless, it seems an example from the Python [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) suggests I can iterate with `csv.DictReader`:

```
with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'd like to do by using these functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), like this

```
import csv, itertools

with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvfile), 100):
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

`islice` will create an iterator from the iterable object you pass and it will allow you iterate till the limit, you pass as the second parameter.

---

Apart from that, if you want to count yourself, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, like this

```
for index, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(csvfile)):
    if index >= 100:
        break
    print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```